# Does multiplying with a unitary matrix change the spectral norm of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

We know that the spectral norm of a matrix $A \in \Bbb K(n,n)$

$$\left \| A \right \| _2=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^{^*}A)}$$

I need to prove that multiplying with an unitary matrix $U \in U(n)$ from the left or right does not change the value of the norm i.e.
$$\left \| A \right \| _2 = \left \| UA \right \| _2 = \left \| AU \right \| _2$$
I was able to prove that 
$$\left \| UA \right \| _2=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}((UA)^{^*}(UA))}$$
$$=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^{^*}U^{^*}UA)}$$
$$=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(A^{^*}A)}=\left \| A \right \| _2$$
since for unitary matrices $$U^{^*}U = I$$

I have no idea how to prove the the argument when multiplying from the right. This has been my approach.
$$\left \| AU \right \| _2=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}((AU)^{^*}(AU))}$$
$$=\sqrt{\lambda_{\text{max}}(U^{^*}A^{^*}AU)}$$
I've really got no idea on what to do next. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key fact is that the nonzero eigenvalues of $AB$ and $BA$ are always the same.  So in particular $$\lambda_{\text{max}}(U^* A^* A U) = \lambda_{\text{max}}(U U^* A^* A) = \lambda_{\text{max}}(A^* A)$$